# embed php emoji library with php to accept input and display from a mobile device

Tags: php, emoji

i understand this question was asked before however the other thread was not of much help to me.

i have the code from [Emoji](http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/) php library that i found on line. the demo works just fine however im having trouble embedding it to my site.

any thoughts on how to embed this library with my site so it will accept input and display from a mobile device such as an iphone?

The demo is set up so it only displays a set set of icons.

```
<?
foreach (array(0x2600, 0x1F493, 0x1F502) as $unified){

    $bytes = "Hello ".emoji_utf8_bytes($unified)." World";

    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>".sprintf('U+%04X', $unified)."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".HtmlSpecialChars(emoji_get_name($unified))."</td>\n";
    echo "<td>$bytes</td>\n";
    echo "<td>".emoji_unified_to_html($bytes)."</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

?>

i would like my site to display emoji when input from a mobile device such as an iphone.
how can i achieve this?

Comment: The demo is simple enough, what is the particular problem in employing this in a real app?

Comment: its just not displaying, the demo is set so it displays only a set set of icons, i need to set it so when i input an emoji from an iphone the website will display it correctly on it. for some reason its not.

Comment: Please update your question, comments are no good for code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library: http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/

Specifically, use `emoji_unified_to_html(emoji_softbank_to_unified($data))` to convert iPhone emoji into HTML.